# correct way to point `npm start` to a package script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

i want to start a `server.js` file located in my package folder

how do i do it properly?

for example, i have a file `node_modules/databased/server.js`:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = new express()

app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

app.listen(3000)

console.log('express started')
```

then in my root `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/databased/server.js"
},
"dependencies": {
    "databased": "file:./my_modules/databased"
}
```

is this the correct way of doing this? this is for a package i am developing

Comment: You probably shouldn't be adding your source code to your node_modules folder.

Comment: my source code goes in the `my_modules` folder, it's linked to with `file:` in my root  `package.json`